# How to deal with the following Informix Dynamic Server starting errors?

Tags: database, informix

While starting IDS server using command `oninit -vy`, more often I am getting the errors like these two:

```
Could not determine encryption mode from page zero.

mt_shm_remove: WARNING: may not have removed all/correct segments.
```

How should I deal with these errors?

Comment: What version of Informix are you using? Did this server ever been online and working?

Comment: Do you shut down Informix cleanly, or do you let the system stop Informix when the system is rebooted?  The encryption warning is puzzling.  Did you migrate an older instance of Informix to run with a newer version?  Which version of Informix are you using and on which platform?

Comment: I use Informix 12.10 in Linux platform , I have multiple instances up and running in my machine and I will shutdown them cleanly .